# Robust fit in Python: weighted and generalized nonlinear least squares

Tags: python, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization, robust

I have a very heteroscedastic data set that has to be fitted by a logistic function. In this respect I have a few quesions.

1. Is there a nonlinear generalised least squares (LS) implmentation in python?
2. What are the advantages of using generalised LS over an iteratively reweighted LS?
3. An additional question regarding `scipy.optiize.least_squares`. There is a keyword `f_scale`, which is commonly set to 0.1. How is it defined in general? I understand that `f_scale` gives the range of the inliers, but how do I determine the optimal range?